# Gantry 5 Grid System same as in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I use this class to display responsive cards via Bootstrap 4

col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12

It means, cards will displays like this:
https://biblsoft.ru/images/monopics/2019-05-31_20-20-08.mp4

How I can make same in Gantry 5?

It have only fixed sizes
http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/advanced/responsive-content

But I need to display 5 cards per line on large screens, 4 cards in medium etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can add bootstrap 4 in your gantry page settings asset option

in the css and js fields add the bootstrap 4 CDN links and your bootstrap cards will start functioning.